# How to create reusable groups of widgets or layouts in PyQT using python

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm creating my first app with PyQt and I'm a little stuck on the approach for how I would create reusable groups of widgets. I'm creating a To Do list manager app and want to be able to have a button to "Add Task" which when clicked will add a set of fields for the new task to the screen so that the user can add in the details.

I therefore want to have a stored set of QWidgets that are added to the screen every time the button is clicked.

I've currently created a new QVBoxLayout class that contains them all so I now just create a new instance of the class, create a new widget and then set the widget layout to the new instance of my layout class.

Is that the best way of doing this or is there another approach that I should be considering?

Comment: Please consider that "what is the best way to do xyz" are normally considered off topic on StackOverflow, mostly because: 1. they are opinion based (while SO aims for *factual* answers); 2. only *you* can know what's the better approach for *your* needs, other people might give good answers to *their* needs, which might not be appropriate to what you have/want/need to do.

Comment: Thanks for that. Maybe I should have rephrased to ask if this was the right way and what the downsides of this approach vs creating a new QWidget class should be?